# vuejs conditional rendering leaving extra html markup

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am new to VueJS and I have a simple HTML markup where I iterate through some objects and render them in html like so:

```
<div v-for="item in some_counter">
 <p v-if="item.some_param1 !== 'None'">
  [[ item.some_param2 ]]
 </p>
</div>
```

However, I notice that even when the condition evaluates to false, I see an extra HTML `<div></div>` markup. This seems very odd to me, coming from the Django world.

How do I avoid this extra markup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `v-if` applies to the element you place it on. So if you want to conditionally include the `<div>` you need to put the `v-if` on the `<div>` (or a parent element). It won't remove the `<div>` just because it is empty.

Technically you can have both `v-for` and `v-if` on the same element but it is generally discouraged as it can be confusing trying to understand which is applied first (see https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-v-if). Instead you should include a wrapping `<template>` for the `v-for`:

```html
<template v-for="item in some_counter">
  <div v-if="item.some_param1 !== 'None'">
    <p>
      [[ item.some_param2 ]]
    </p>
  </div>
</template>
```

The `<template>` tag is special and won't add an extra element to the finished DOM.

An alternative approach would be to filter the list of items in a computed property and then iterate over the filtered list in your template.

Comment: @skirtie: thank you very much for this. Can I use this <template></template> tag directly in html? or do I have to include it in Vue code? Using as a computed prop is unfortunately not an option :( I would love to know how to use both v-for and v-if in the same element. Could you show me an example for this?

Comment: @JohnJ When you say *'in html'* I assume you're referring to in-DOM templates. You can use `<template>` tags in in-DOM templates but the caveats around table-related elements apply (see https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#DOM-Template-Parsing-Caveats). Your example doesn't seem to include tables so you should be fine.

Comment: thank you VERY much for your detailed anaswer and explanations. Saved some 20 hours because of you - thank you. Answer accepted.

Comment: @JohnJ I've added a link to the official documentation about using `v-for` and `v-if` on the same element.

Comment: thank you again, from what I see, using it in the same line is only a styling issue (which I dont care about) and I prefer to use both in the same line.. From the docs, there does not seem to be any catches.. do you agree?

Comment: @JohnJ This is about using it on the same element, not the same line. As for whether it is a 'styling issue', that depends on what you mean by 'styling issue'. It isn't merely an aesthetic preference if that's what you mean. The 'catch' is that the `v-for` takes priority over `v-if` no matter which order you write the attributes in. This is counter-intuitive and potentially confusing. It should work correctly in your case but I would describe it as a maintainability issue rather than a styling issue.